# I find that this monologue is very hard to understand

Tags: meaning, word-choice, slang, translation

This is monologue from Caddyshack movie, which's become pretty famous internet mem.

And some points of his speech are hard for understanding for me.

> So I jump ship in Hong Kong and make my way over to Tibet, and I get
>   on as a **looper** at a course over in the Himalayas. A looper, you know,
>   a caddy, a looper, a jock. So, I tell them I'm a pro jock, and who do
>   you think they give me? The Dalai Lama, himself. Twelfth son of the
>   Lama. The flowing robes, the grace, bald... striking. So, I'm on the
>   first tee with him. I give him the **driver**. **He hauls off and whacks one**
>   -- big hitter, the Lama -- long, into a ten-thousand foot crevice, right at the base of this glacier. And do you know what the Lama says?
>   Gunga galunga...gunga -- gunga galunga. So we finish the **eighteenth**
>   and he's gonna stiff me. And I say, "Hey, Lama, hey, how about a
>   little something, you know, for the effort, you know." And he says,
>   "Oh, uh, there won't be any money, but when you die, on your deathbed,
>   you will receive total consiousness." **So I got that goin' for me**,
>   which is nice.

Hard parts are bold.

1. I didn't find that kind of profession 'looper' can mean?
2. Gave him 'driver'? What should that mean?
3. I don't understand that following sentence means at all
4. Finish the eighteenth? Again, no idea. Eighteenth as 1980 or what?
5. And finally what does **I got that goin' for me** mean?

Comment: It's about the game of golf.  He explains what a looper is in the next sentence: *A looper, you know, a caddy...*.  A *driver* is a kind of golf club.  You whack the golf ball with the golf club.  There are eighteen holes on a golf course.  To have something going for you, means you have that as an asset, a plus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jim’s comment has explained almost everything:

> It’s about the game of golf. He explains what a looper is in the next sentence: *A looper, you know, a caddy....* A driver is a kind of golf club. You whack the golf ball with the golf club. There are eighteen holes on a golf course. To have something going for you, means you have that as an asset, a plus.

As another example of *looper* as a synonym for *caddy*, see the book **[Loopers: A Caddie's Twenty-Year Golf Odyssey](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0770437184)**.

Some pictures of drivers appear in [google images](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=929&bih=529&q=driver&oq=driver&gs_l=img.3..0l10.2224.3124.0.3359.6.6.0.0.0.0.77.448.6.6.0....0...1ac.1.32.img..0.6.448.uENgk3VBvwE#hl=en&q=golf+driver&tbm=isch).  They have larger heads than other kinds of golf clubs.  *Woods* is an older term, from the material used in the head of a driver, but perhaps is no longer technologically relevant.

“We finish the eighteenth” refers to finishing the full round of golf.  At that point the narrator wants the Dalai Lama to pay a tip or fee.  No money is forthcoming, but a sort of blessing (“on your deathbed, ... total consciousness” ie awareness) is offered, which is something positive (“I got that goin’ for me”).